# Solr : multiple indexes

Tags: solr, indexing

One of our business requirements require a new index to be created apart from the one already existing. The structure of the documents in this new index will be different from the ones available in the existing index. One of the modules of our application needs to query this new index to get the required data.

Can someone please suggest how this can be achieved? The Solr version we are using is 3.5. We already have an 'index' folder inside solr\data folder. I believe a new index folder needs to be created at the same location and data needs to be imported separately in this new index.

Which approach I should take up to achieve this?

Please help.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a 2nd solr core...

here is an tutorial:

http://www.pinoyoracledba.com/2011/05/solr-adding-new-core.html

Comment: @anand tiwari If that answer was helpful, please accept my answer. This is, how stackoverflow works.